# Vaadin. Event Queue

Tags: events, tree, vaadin

I`m working on a Vaadin application, so that on the left side of a screen there is a tree. When user uses navigation keys, items of a tree are selected and data (about them) is loaded to the right side of the screen. But it causes a big stream of data between client and server and client needs to wait while server will process all previous selected items. (if user navigates quickly - that is true in most cases). Is there an event queue, so that I can process the last selected item not all events that were selected during "quick" navigation?

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

The same is true if you are mouse clicking on the tree items quickly. I got selected element one and information is displayed for a one of previous my "quick" selection with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an event queue, so that I can process the last selected item
>   not all events that were selected during "quick" navigation?

In short, and to the best of my knowledge, no.

The only suggestion I can make is to make some kind of timer that only reacts to a selection after a pause of say 0.5/1 second. This would be a little tricky, though, as it would require the use of polling/or push. See [this discussion on how to do that](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/231271)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you own simple event "queue", for example:

1. all events collect into you own queue
2. all events separate by event-producer (you tree or something else)
3. after event-idle by producer (e.g. 2000ms) you must process event queue and fire last event in stack